# Mock Symfony repository in controller integration tests

Tags: php, symfony, mocking, phpunit

Symfony 6.3. I have a controller:

```
class FooController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(private readonly FooRepository $fooRepository)
    {
    }
    
    #[Route('/foo/{name}', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function show(string $name): JsonResponse
    {
        $foo = $this->fooRepository->findOneBy(['name' => $name]);
        // do stuff...
        return $this->json(['data' => $foo]);
    }
}
```

And I want to test that when I hit that route the `findOneBy` method is called:

```
public function testFoo()
{
    $foo = //....
    $fooRepository = $this->createMock(FooRepository::class);
    $fooRepository->expects(self::once())
            ->method('findOneBy')
            ->willReturn($foo);
    $this->client->jsonRequest('GET', 'foo/'.$foo->getName());
}
```

The problem is, when I run this test, it fails:

> Expectation failed for method name is "findOneBy" when invoked 1 time(s).
> Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

I also, in the same test, check the response and it seems to just bypass the mock and grab the object from the database and return it with a `200`. I assume this is happening because the `AbstractBrowser` is making a request at another level than the tests are operating on, but then I'm not sure how to test that the repository method is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Not something that I have tried myself, but based on the documentation on [symfony mocking dependencies](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#mocking-dependencies), you're missing the part of setting the mocked instance into your container. So just adding that into your test method:

```
public function testFoo()
{
    $foo = //....
    $fooRepository = $this->createMock(FooRepository::class);
    $fooRepository->expects(self::once())
        ->method('findOneBy')
        ->willReturn($foo);

    $container = static::getContainer();
    $container->set(FooRepository::class, $fooRepository);

    $this->client->jsonRequest('GET', 'foo/'.$foo->getName());
}
```

Comment: Yes I had tried that but it didn't help